# End IF without block IF compile error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run this macro to shift data up on multiple sheets after the rows have been deleted. I keep getting a compile error

> End if Without Block If

Here is my VBA code:

```
Sub shiftmeup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("contactunder") '/// The underhood of my contacts
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Deposits")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Lending")
    Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("Client Notes")

    With ws.Range("D11:BJ392")
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then .Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Next

    With ws1.Range("E11:l392")
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then .Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Next


    With ws2.Range("E11:Y392")
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then .Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Next

    With ws3.Range("E11:E392")
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then .Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp

            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Always format and indent your code correctly, otherwise you don't see your issues (I did that for you in your question). Now you see that the first 3 `With` have no `End With`. Also there is a `End If` that is too much because all your `If` statements are 1-liners and then doen't need a `End If`. • Additionally I recommend to use descriptive variable names instead of `ws1`, `ws2`, …

Comment: + The first three If also have no End if

Comment: @Pierre44 1-liner `If` statements are not allowed to have a `End If`. The `End If` in the 4th `With` is too much and needs to be removed instead.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you are correct Sir. I removed the last End if and added 3 more "End With" at the end, my code is running correct now! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always format and indent your code correctly, otherwise you don't see your issues (I did that for you in your question).

Now you see that the first 3 `With` have no `End With`. Every `With` needs its own `End With`!

Also there is a `End If` that is too much because all your `If` statements are 1-liners and then doen't need a `End If`.

There are 2 types of `If` statements:

1. 1-liners `If … Then … Else`

   ```
   If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then .Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
   ```

   Note that in 1-line-statements no `End If` is allowed.
2. Multi liners

   ```
   If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then 
       .Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
   ```

You cannot mix them.

---

Additionally I recommend to use descriptive variable names instead of `ws1`, `ws2`, … Which makes your code much more readable and better maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

@Peh already told you about your issue

Here's a possible refactoring of your code

first, assign a repetitive task to a specific routine:

```
Sub DeleteSheetRows(rng As Range)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) > 0 Then rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

then call that specific routine from your "main" code:

```
Sub shiftmeup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheetNames As Variant, rangeAddresses As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    sheetNames = Array("contactunder", "Deposits", "Lending", "Client Notes")
    rangeAddresses = Array("D11:BJ392", "E11:l392", "E11:Y392", "E11:E392")

    With ThisWorkbook ' reference desired workbook
        For i = 1 To UBound(sheetNames) ' loop through sheet names
            DeleteSheetRows .Worksheets(sheetNames(i)).Range(rangeAddresses(i)) ' call rows deleting routin passing current worksheet proper range
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like your edit of my module, its less code and calls multiple sheets through an array. I will try it out as well!